# Sequences and accumulation points in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis

I'm studying general topology and a question has come to my mind.

Given a sequence $x$ (i.e. map from the set $N$ of natural numbers) in a topological space and given a point p of the latter, we say that $*p$ is a special point for $x*$ if the $x$-preimage of every neighbourhood of $p$ is cofinal in the canonical order of $N$ (that is, for every neighbourhood $I$ of $p$ and for every natural number $n$, there exists a natural number m>n such that $x(m)$ belongs to $I$).

Let's consider the following claim: *if $p$ is an accumulation point for the image of $x$, then $p$ is a special point for $x*$. Initially I believed it to be false, but until now I haven't succeeded in finding a counterexample.

Is it true? Or, if it's not, how could one disprove it?
It would be also appreciated if anyone mentioned a more standard naming for the above property.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format the mathematics in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: Let $X = \{u_1, u_2, c\}$ be the space on three points with topology given by the open sets $X$, $\emptyset$, and $\{u_1, u_2\}$. Let $x\colon \mathbb{N} \to X$ be the sequence given by $x_0 = u_1$ and $x_k = c$ for all $k > 0$. Then $u_2$ is an accumulation point of $x(\mathbb{N}) = \{u_1, c\}$ since all its open neighborhoods contain $u_1$, but clearly it is not special for $x$: The preimage $x^{-1}(\{u_1, u_2\}) = \{0\}$ is not cofinal in $\mathbb{N}$.